# mysql connection on vista using java jdbc, communicationException, tried the common answers

Tags: java, mysql, windows-vista

I am having newbie problems getting a mysql connection using java on a Vista 64 bit platform.  I have been reading web information from others with a similar problem, so far with no luck.  This is probably due to a lack of understanding on my part.  I can see port 3306 is listening using netstat -an.  I disabled the MS firewall and installed webroot as my firewall and mysql is allowed.  I have added the path to the JDBC driver jar file in the -cp option. Debugging seems to indicate that the driver is not registered, but I can do all the mysql functions on the database from the command line.

I have seen the following exception:
    com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

This is my output:

```
C:\Users\Jerry>java -cp c:\Users\jerry;c:\ProgramFiles(86)\ConnectorJ\mysql-connector-java-5.1.11-bin dbaccess 
FOO:  jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/access03tstroot
Cannot connect to database server
SQLEXCEPTION: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at dbaccess.mysqlConnection(dbaccess.java:77)
at dbaccess.main(dbaccess.java:59)
```

I print out messages with what I am sending and set breakpoints to stop in DriverManager.getConnection.  There is a piece of the code that checks for a registered driver, I think.

The code fails during isDriverAllowed(aDriver.driver, callCL)
It is my understanding that the Class.forName call will register a new driver when found.
The loop makes two passes, first looking for the ODBC Driver, then the com.mysql.jdbc.driver.

The callerCL = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@1054f93
The url is jdbc:mysql:/loacalhost:3306/access03tst

```
    for(DriverInfo aDriver : registeredDrivers) {
        // If the caller does not have permission to load the driver then
        // skip it.
        if(isDriverAllowed(aDriver.driver, callerCL)) {
            try {
                println("    trying " + aDriver.driver.getClass().getName());
                Connection con = aDriver.driver.connect(url, info);
                if (con != null) {
                    // Success!
                    println("getConnection returning " + aDriver.driver.getClass().getName());
                    return (con);
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                if (reason == null) {
                    reason = ex;
                }
            }

        } else {
            println("    skipping: " + aDriver.getClass().getName());
        }

    }
```

My compile command is:

```
javac -d . -sourcepath . -cp c:\Users\Jerry;c:\ProgramFiles(86)\ConnectorJ\mysql-connector-java-5.1.11-bin c:\Users\Jerry\dbaccess.java
```

My execute command is:

```
java -cp c:\Users\jerry;c:\ProgramFiles(86)\ConnectorJ\mysql-connector-java-5.1.11-bin dbaccess
```

My code follows:

```
package dbaccess;

import java.sql.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class dbaccess
{
    // Public static indicates that this is a class variable not an instance
    // variable. It is part of the class as a whole.
    public static Connection conn = null;
    public boolean success;

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        init();
        mysqlConnection();
        getList catList = new getList();
        boolean status = catList.success;
    }
    public static void mysqlConnection()
    {
       try
       {
          String dbName  =  "access03tst";
          String userName = "";
          String password = "";
          String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
          String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.driver";
          String foo = url+dbName+userName+password;
          System.out.println("FOO: " + foo);

          //Register the JDBC driver for MySQL.
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); //.newInstance ();

          System.out.println("Surprise we got here ");
          conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName+userName+password);
          System.out.println ("Database connection established");
          System.out.println("URL: " + url);
          System.out.println("Connection: " + conn);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server");
       }
       finally
       {
          if (conn != null)
          {
              try
              {
                 conn.close ();
                 System.out.println ("Database connection terminated");
              }
              catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
          }
       }  // end finally
    }

    public static void init()
    {
    //
    // Public static indicates that this is a class variable not an instance
    // variable. It is part of the class as a whole.
    conn = null;
    boolean success = false;
    boolean CatRequest = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer.  I was using the syntax for the url found in many references.

```
      String userName = "root";
      String password = "password";
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName+userName+password);
```

This results in a url passed into the getConnection code that appears as
   "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbaccess03tstrootpassword"
MySQL looks for a database named dbaccess03tstrootpassword which does not exist and results in a failed Connection of null.

I changed the code to the following syntax and I got a valid connection.

```
String urlFormated = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/"
              + dbName 
              + "?user="
              + userName
              + "&password="
              + password;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(urlFormated);
```